# Python regex match world but exclude certain phrase

Tags: python, regex

I got the following scenario:

```
1)car is on fire
2)found fire crews on scene
```

I want to match fire when keyword "crews" NOT present. The other word, I want to 1) return "fire", and 2) returns nothing.

```
regex = re.compile(r'\bfire (?!crews)\b')
```

but it failed to match "car is on fire" due to missing space after fire.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need regex,`if "fire" in line and "crews" not in line ...`

Comment: Thanks for replying. The reason I didn't do this way was that I got a bunch of regex expression saved in json file. So I want to do it automatically instead of coding for each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex would be,

```
\bfire\b(?!.*\bcrews\b)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jH6qM3/1)

If you want to print the whole line then your regex would be,

```
.*\bfire\b(?!.*\bcrews\b).*
```

Python code,

```
>>> import re
>>> data = """car is on fire
... found fire crews on scene"""
>>> m = re.search(r'\bfire\b(?!.*\bcrews\b)', data, re.M)
>>> m.group()
'fire'
>>> m = re.search(r'.*\bfire\b(?!.*\bcrews\b).*', data, re.M)
>>> m.group()
'car is on fire'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex here. You can just check with the `in` keyword:

```
if "fire" in line and "crews" not in line:
    print("fire")
```

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed that. Your comment was first; in my defence I didn't see it and wasn't copying it as an answer. If you add an answer I'll delete mine.

Comment: you're fine, don't worry about it